# I can't download linux with wsl, Invalid command line option: --install

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
wsl --install --online

Invalid command line option: --install
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

I need to see the linux versions I can download but I get this output. Why ?

Comment: According to the docs: ["The `wsl --install` simplified install command requires that you join the Windows Insiders Program and install a preview build of Windows 10 (OS build 20262 or higher)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)

Answer (score 2):

Check which build of windows you are on. I had this error when I was on builds less than 18917. You can find this in your "System Information" application

Comment: I am on Build 19042 (above the minimum required) and having the same issue.